# Кириллические URL возвращают 404 на локальном сервере (и корректно работают на GitHub Pages)

Tags: веб-программирование, кодировка, url, jekyll

Я работаю над статическим сайтом на Jekyll и у меня возникла проблема с загрузкой страниц с кириллическими URL. Когда я разворачиваю сайт локально и пытаюсь перейти по ссылке, содержащей кириллические символы, меня выкидывает на страницу 404.

Допустим, мой файл с публикацией называется "кабели.md". Соответственно, он должен открыться по этому URL: [https://127.0.0.1:4000/category/кабели/](https://127.0.0.1:4000/category/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8/). В данном случае я получаю страницу 404.

Меняю название документа на "kabels.md" или на любое другое название, содержащее только латинские символы, и вижу корректное отображение публикации по адресу https://127.0.0.1:4000/category/kabels/.

В то же время сайт развернут на GitHub Pages и там, когда я перехожу по той же ссылке: [https://domen.com/category/кабели/](https://domen.com/category/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8/) , я вижу корректное отображение статьи про кабели.

Очевидно, что проблема кроется где-то в кодировках кириллических символов. Моя ОС - Windows.
Может у кого-то есть идеи, как можно решить эту проблему?